# Kivy: ScreenManager Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am struggling with Kivy's screen manager function. I want to set it up so that I can transition between screens, but I'm having trouble understanding the documentation. I think I may be misunderstanding because I am not very familiar with classes.

Trying to run this code causes a crash. 
It gives the error message:

```
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 254, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__ (kivy\_event.c:5332)
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I'd rather not mess around with the kivy language, please help me to understand how to make this work in python 3.

```
"""
Python 3.6.4
Kivy 1.10.0

Combines various .py files and
allows the game to run.
"""

__author__ = "RidiculousName"
__date__ = "Jan. 2018"

import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainMenu(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # declares widget buttons
        background = Image(source="Img\\BG.png",
                           pos=(0, 0))

        start_button = Button(pos=(25, 75),
                              background_normal="Img\\Start.png",
                              background_down="Img\\Start_Down.png",
                              size_hint=(.1, .1))

        load_button = Button(pos=(225, 75),
                             background_normal="Img\\Load.png",
                             background_down="Img\\Load_Down.png",
                             size_hint=(.1, .1))

        options_button = Button(pos=(425, 75),
                                background_normal="Img\\Options.png",
                                background_down="Img\\Options_Down.png",
                                size_hint=(.15, .1))

        quit_button = Button(pos=(708, 75),
                             background_normal="Img\\Quit.png",
                             background_down="Img\\Quit_Down.png",
                             size_hint=(.1, .1))
        quit_button.bind(on_press=sys.exit)

        # Adds widgets in order
        self.add_widget(background)
        self.add_widget(start_button)
        self.add_widget(load_button)
        self.add_widget(options_button)
        self.add_widget(quit_button)



class BanditKing(App, ScreenManager):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
        super(BanditKing, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        sm = ScreenManager
        sm.add_widget(ScreenManager(name="MainMenu"))
        self.title = "Bandit King"
        self.icon = "Window_Icon.png"
        return sm



def main():
    Config.set("graphics", "width", "1600")
    Config.set("graphics", "height", "900")
    Config.write()
    BanditKing().run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widgets that you add to a `ScreenManager` should be type `Screen`. So `MainMenu` should extend `Screen` instead of `FloatLayout`. 'Screen' is a `RelativeLayout`, so it shouldn't affect your code much.

And your `BanditKing` class `build()` should create a `ScreenManager` and return it, rather than extend it:

```
class BanditKing(App):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
        super(BanditKing, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainMenu(name="MainMenu"))
        self.title = "Bandit King"
        self.icon = "Window_Icon.png"
        return sm
```